# How to set Password validation

Tags: python

I am using this `QLineEdit` to take password from user I want the password to contains the following letter:

1. At least One Capital Letter.
2. At least One Numeric.
3. At least One Special Character.
4. Minimum length should be 12 characters.

how can I achieve this password validation.

Comment: You must be more specific. What should happen if the user does not comply with those restrictions or how should the GUI behave when it does not comply with those rules?

Comment: @eyllanesc It's not related to GUI, I just wanted to know how to impose those restriction in my ```QLineEdit```, I think i need to write some regex expression but don't know how to write it. that's why I asked the question.

Comment: The GUI is the QLineEdit. So that you understand me I am going to give trivial examples: What should happen if in the first 12 characters the user did not press any number or did not press a special character or a capital letter? On the other hand, what is a special character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to check the validness of password then you can do this using regex.

Here's the code

```
import re
password = input()

if re.search(r".{12}", password) and re.search(r"[A-Z]", password) and re.search(r"[0-9]", password) and re.search(r"\W", password):
    print("Valid password")
else:
    print("Invalid password")
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not what the OP is asking.

Comment: Thanks it works. I am just passing the entered string in my ```QLineEdit``` to a function to check the password validation and this regular expression works like a charm.

Comment: @VinayKumarShukla If you consider that this is the answer you expected then the problem has nothing to do with Qt (not pyqt5) but a validation (not a restriction) of a string. A restriction implies that the user cannot place any restricted character.